# Show activity indicator when iphone camera button pressed

Tags: iphone, camera, uiactivityindicatorview

How to add activity indicator when camera button (USE button) is pressed after making a snap.

It looks like hangs for few seconds.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
[indicator sizeToFit];
indicator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);

indicator.tag = 1;
[self.view addSubview:indicator];
[indicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
indicator.center = self.view.center;
indicator.hidden = FALSE;
[indicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: Hey man i mean was to add activity indicator at the camera disappear....
i know how to use activity indicator but how to use at that place....